# Unix time to Humanreadable Date and Time

Tags: lua, roblox, unix-timestamp

Im working in lua with out date support so what are some ways th convert unix millisecond time to time and date

mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss

i have the time and day but year and month are hard

Thanks.

EDIT: ALL I Need is Day of Month now I Figured out the other parts

EDIT: the first part of code NO DAY OF MONTH and still working on DST

```
 TIMEZONE=-5
 DAYLIGHTSAVING=0--NOT DONE

 while true do
  t=tick()
  y=math.floor(1970+ t /31556926)
  ds=((1970+t/31556926)-y)*31556926
  m=math.floor(ds/2629743)+1
  d=math.floor(ds/86400)+1
  md=0--NOT DONE
  wd=d%7+6
  print(md,wd)
  h=math.floor(math.fmod(t,60*60*24)/3600) + 5 + (TIMEZONE) + (DAYLIGHTSAVING)
  mn= math.floor(math.fmod(t,60*60*24)/60 - 60*h)
  s= math.floor(math.fmod(math.fmod(t,60*60*24),60))
  print(m,d,y)
  print(h,mn,s)
  wait(1)
 end
```

i will make it nicer afer i get day of month and DST

Comment: It would be nice if you shared how you did the other stuff. Might help future googlers!

Comment: This runs on the roblox game so there is no OS.date() because there is no global OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people who are wondering....

Heres how i did it:

```
TIMEZONE=-5
DST=0

dm={31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31}

while true do
t=tick()
y=math.floor(1970+ t /31556926)
ds=((1970+t/31556926)-y)*31556926
m=math.floor(ds/2629743)+1
d=math.floor(ds/86400)+1
md=math.floor(((ds/2629743+1)-m)*dm[m])+1
wd=d%7+6
if(m11)then DST=0 else DST=1 end
if(m==3)then if(md>=14)then DST=1 else DST=0 end end
if(m==11)then if(md>=7)then DST=0 else DST=1 end end
h=math.floor(math.fmod(t,60*60*24)/3600) + 5 + (TIMEZONE) + (DST)
mn= math.floor(math.fmod(t,60*60*24)/60 - 60*(h-DST))
s= math.floor(math.fmod(math.fmod(t,60*60*24),60))
wait(1)
end
```

Comment: use the % operator, its faster than using math.fmod.